# Canvas app is not working because of 'X-Frame option' in response header of external site

Tags: visualforce, canvas

I have created an canvas app, in that I'm trying to access one external website. But when I'm trying to access that external website I'm getting error as

> Refused to display 'external url' in a frame because it set
>   'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

I searched about this problem then I got to know that as `X-Frame-Options` is set to `SAMEORIGIN`, so server is simply refusing the request.

I want to access that website in canvas app, can anybody please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to work with the people responsible for maintaining the website. For security purposes, they have chosen to disable allowing their site to be included in an IFrame and unless they change their `X-Frame-Options` to also whitelist Salesforce this will be impossible.

**Update**

There are three options for `X-Frame-Options`: SAMEORIGIN, ALLOW-FROM, and DENY. SAMEORIGIN allows embedding from any page within the same domain and DENY prevents embedding everywhere. You would need to convince this company to switch to ALLOW-FROM so they can maintain a list of approved URI who are allowed to embed their page in an IFrame.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mike. But if suppose 'X-Frame options' is removed from response header by peoples maintaining that website, then there will be major security issue. Is there any another way to overcome this issue?

Comment: You would have to get the website to whitelist you. I'll update my answer.

Comment: ALLOW-FROM is partially supported, it will not work for google chrome. Please check 'Browser compatibility' section in this link : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

Comment: Hmm, it works for me but http://www.enhanceie.com/test/clickjack/ shows Chrome isn't always correct.